# Auto filling in fields of an iframe and submitting the form using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, submit

I need to access the below iframe with javascript to allow me to auto input a set username and set password in the form and then submit it. :

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" id="mainForm"></iframe>
```

how is this done?

Comment: Is the Iframe on the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: No i getting the source of the iframe from an external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents you from manipulating the content of an Iframe from an different domain. This was put in place to prevent Iframed content from hijacking your privacy.

What you want cannot be done.